# getting null while passing list data from jquery ajax to mvc controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am always getting null value in parameter in first submit.Further Submit on button will giving me the list.

JQuery Part :

```
function passMTMToServer() {
        var MTMData = [];
        $("#tblMtm").children("tbody").children("tr").each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var $tds = $(this).children('td');
            statusID = $tds.eq(1).find('input').val();
            tld = $tds.eq(3).find('input').val();
            order = $tds.eq(5).find('input').val();
            MTMData.push({ st_testID: 0, st_statusID: statusID, tldID: tld, orderBy: order });
        });

        MTMData = JSON.stringify({ 'obj': MTMData });


        $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../Status/SaveMTM',
            data: MTMData,
            traditional: true,
            success: function () {
                alert('Data Passed to Server');
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    }
```

Controller Code :

```
public ActionResult SaveMTM(List<MTMStatusModel> obj)
{

    //perform submit in st_test_mtm_status
    return View("SaveTest");
}
```

Comment: Can you show what MTMData becomes before you send it?

Comment: Do you have [HttpPost] attribute on that action?

Comment: I have tried with HTTPPost attribute on controller,Not working.

Comment: MTM data looks like :    {"obj":[{"st_testID":0,"st_statusID":"1","tldID":"2","orderBy":"3"},{"st_testID":0,"st_statusID":"1","tldID":"2","orderBy":"3"}]}

Comment: Can you update your controller action code to include the attributes you're applying?

Comment: Your exact code works without any problem. Did you compare both the requests? I mean the first which does not send the data and the second which does? Can you show us the code which invokes the `passMTMToServer`?

Answer (score 2):

Ajax request:

Name your parameter while sending if your controller is expecting it with different name

```
$.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../Status/SaveMTM',
        data: {obj: MTMData },
        traditional: true,
        success: function () {
            alert('Data Passed to Server');
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
```

And at controller:

If you will post something to this action, add [HttpPost] Attribute

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveMTM(List<MTMStatusModel> obj)
    {

        //perform submit in st_test_mtm_status
        return View("SaveTest");
    }
```

Comment: Please explain what was wrong and what did you fix...

Comment: Its working fine after first post but for the first post value is null.

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing the data you passing to ajax like below.

Note: **Make sure your data is a List of MTMStatusModel.**

```
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../Status/SaveMTM',
    data: { 'obj' : MTMData},
    traditional: true,
    success: function () {
        alert('Data Passed to Server');
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: yes its a list of MTMStatusModel.

Comment: Is the above code helps you to get the answer.